# Are there any hidden areas or easter eggs in Lego Batman?

Tags: nintendo-wii, lego-batman

Are there any secret areas that would allow me special privileges in Lego Batman for the Wii?

Comment: Your tag reads Lego Batman 2 - are you talking about the first or second game?

Comment: 1st game there is no tag for it tho

Comment: Back on topic...  are you familiar with the "red bricks"?

Comment: yes I am and I have all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You acquire `Special privileges` or `Easter eggs` by catch and activate the red bricks.

> I have all of them – Young Guilo

If you have them already you just need to activate them.

1. Pause the game
2. In the menu go to Extras
3. Activate the Extras that you want and Unpause

Comment: i already have activated them

Comment: then I don't quite understand your question

Comment: I was wondering if there were any other secret areas like a map to play on that isn't an actual map ie. a gym to just mess around in or something